# Reverse for 'todo-user' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to add a user when clicking on a link but I'm getting the following error :

> Reverse for 'todo-user' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['todo/(?P<todo_id>[^/]+)/$']

**My views.py**

```
def todo_user(request, todo_id):
    todo.username.add(request.user)
    todo.save()
    return render(request, '/')
```

**Template**

```
<a href="{% url 'todo-user' todo.id %}"></a>
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('validate/<todo_id>/', views.todo_user, name='todo-user),
```

**Views.py for the template render :**

```
def home(request, token):
            todo_instance = get_object_or_404(Todo, token=token)
            context = {
                'token': todo_instance.token,
                'name': todo_instance.name,
       }
       return render(request, '/', context)
```

Thanks to you guys !

Comment: The error shows that `todo.id` is empty, so you should show the view that is used to render the template in the first place.

Comment: Thanks ! I have edited the question, i hope Its good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you're referring to a `todo` variable:

```
<a href="{% url 'todo-user' todo.id %}"></a>
```

but in your context used to render the template, no such variable is defined. Add

```
'todo': todo_instance
```

to your context. You can remove 'token' and 'name' and use `{{ todo.name }}` in you template instead.